# ASP.NET Debugger is not stopping at server-side breakpoint when CallBack is called

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, debugging, webforms, callback

I am debugging code on a webforms site and the javascript runs a callback which then goes to the code behind but skips my breakpoints since the server-side code is running on a separate thread. Any tips on debugging this?

The JS:

```
testCallBack.Callback(param1);
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub testCallBack_Callback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CallBackEventArgs) Handles testCallBack.Callback
       'My break point is in this function
       functionThatisErroring()
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint in the function and the debugger isn't stopping. Instead it just skips to the on CallBack error function in JS which displays an alert error message.

```
<ClientEvents>
      <CallbackError EventHandler="testCallBack_Error" />
</ClientEvents>
```

The server-side error is getting sent to my email but is very general so can't figure it out unless I can step through the function.

Comment: Can you show some code? Usually breakpoints always break even when code runs asynchronously, except when debugging Silverlight which needs a special configuration from the project properties in order for it to work.

Comment: Not sure if showing code would help. Basically the JavaScript looks like this: testCallBack.Callback(param1); Then in the code behind there is a Sub that handles: testCallBack.Callback. In this Sub a function is called and that is where the code is erroring. I put a breakpoint in the function and the debugger isn't stopping. Instead it just skips to the on CallBack error function in JS which displays an alert error message. The server-side error is getting sent to my email but is very general so can't figure it out unless I can step through the function.